# Adding objects created with inheritance to linked list and implementing their methods

Tags: java

I am trying to store objects of different "types" in an linked list.  I have several unique "type" classes that inherit from `ProtoType` (only one is shown here, there are 5 types all together).

When I create a new object I can access all the methods in it using "type1.someMethods".  What I do not know , is how to  iterate thru the list and get the  methods of each of the different "types" based on their location in the list. I thought I would be able to use "typeList.get( int index).someMethods().  I am only able to use the methods associated with a LinkedList.

The Parent Class

```
public class ProtoType {

private int ID;
private int x;
private String type;
private int randomNumber;

public ProtoType(int ID, int x, String type ) {

   this.ID = ID;
   this.x = x;
   this.type = type;
   this.randomNumber = randomNumber;
}


 public int getID() {
    return ID;
}


public  int getX() {
   return x;
}

public void randomNumberGenerator(int max, int min) {
   Random r = new Random();
   randomNumber = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + 1;

}
public int getRandomNum() {
   return randomNumber;
}
}
```

Child Class

```
public class Type1 extends ProtoType {

public Type1(int ID, int x, String type) {
    super(ID, x, type);

}
public void preformAction(){
    System.out.println(getRandomNum());
    switch (getRandomNum()){

    case 1:
    case 2:
        //Some action
        break;
    case 3: 
        //some action
        break;
    case 4:
        //some action
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

Main class

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class TestMAin {

public static   void main(String[] args) {

   LinkedList typeList = new LinkedList();

   Type1 t1 = new Type1(1, 12, "type1");
      typeList.add(0, t1);
   Type1 t2 = new Type1(2, 13, "type1");
      typeList.add(1, t2);

   }
//////////////
// the issue
//iterate thru the array get the type 
//implement the methods of that type
/////////////

}
```

Comment: You want to know what methods it implements? Why don't you just check to see what class it's an instance of?

Comment: This is a design error wrapped in a feature request. What are you actually trying to do? There's certainly a much better way than having an untyped list of objects.

Comment: In the end I need to loop thru the list and based on the object i will need to implement certain methods.  So if I am at index 12 I get the object type and implement certain actions based on the type.  as I move along some instances will be deleted and others added.  I need a way of storing retrieving and deleting the different instances and then implementing their methods.

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 suggestions depending on one thing. Are your inherited classes using method overriding?

Example:

```
public class ParentClass {
    public void method() {}
}

public class ChildA extends ParentClass {
    @Override
    public void method() {}
}

public class ChildB extends ParentClass {
    @Override
    public void method() {}
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<ParentClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new ChildA());
        list.add(new ChildB());

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            list.get(i).method(); //Will class the appropriate sub-classes implementation of method().
        }
    }
}
```

If you're not wishing to use overridden methods, the instanceof operator might be what you're looking for.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<ParentClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new ChildA());
        list.add(new ChildB());

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            ParentClass obj = list.get(i);

            if (obj instanceof ChildA) {
                obj.childAMethod();
            }
            else if (obj instanceof ChildB) {
                obj.childBMethod();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you find yourself relying on the instanceof operator you might need to have a look at your programs structure as it isn't considered the best for OOP design.